# "Clean Solution" menu error after upgrading Visual Studion 2017 to version 15.3.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

We're working on ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.1 project (that we don't yet want to upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.0). However we have upgraded VS2017 from ver 15.2 to ver 15.3.3. But after VS2017 upgrade, we have started getting following error whenever we click on menu Build-->Clean Solution of VS2017. However when we run Build-->Clean Solution again, command works fine without error. It's not a show stopper it's just an annoyance to click the menu twice to make it work:

> [Failure] Could not find file 'C:\MyProjFolder\src\MyProject\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\MyProject.AssemblyInfo.cs'.

**MyProj.csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>MyProj</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>MyProj</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-MyProj-6af8ade3-87ff-4468-a9ce-8bb69c696ab8</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\MyProjP.pubxml" />
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml" />
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile1.pubxml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\Views">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="2.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.3.327" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus.Core" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: If you can repro this with a new 1.1 project, is's a VS bug you should report with MS.

Comment: Try to delete the `C:\MyProjFolder\src\MyProject\bin` and `C:\MyProjFolder\src\MyProject\obj` folders. Will probably solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds like it has nothing to do with doing a clean on your solution, but it seems Visual Studio is having issues with auto-generated files and Intellisense.

It is a bit subtle, but Visual Studio (I use VS Professional 2017 v15.6.4) is actually switching you to the Intellisense output after you clean the solution.

Notice that the "Show output from:" dropdown menu switches to "IntelliSense" after the clean:

[image: Screenshot of Output Window from Visual Studio]

It has been reported to Microsoft and you can keep track of this bug here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12202